# How to require an additional charge for the first-time users in stripe subscription?

Tags: reactjs, django, stripe-payments

I am building a Saas project.
This system has several pricing plans.
**The first-time users should pay an additional amount of money.
This money is charged only once per account and is not required anymore after the user paid once regardless of the purchased plan.**
It seems Stripe have no such option.
And if I use the normal checkout method and subscription method together, the user should pay twice the first time.
This is bad for the user experience.
I would be appreciate if you could help me to solve this problem.
In addition, I am using Django+React for the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the subscription you can use `add_invoice_items` to have one-time items [added to the first invoice only](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/subscription#first-invoice-extra):

```
stripe.Subscription.create(
  customer="{{ CUSTOMER_ID }}",
  items=[{
    'price': '{{ RECURRING_PRICE_ID }}'
  }],
  add_invoice_items=[{
    'price': '{{ PRICE_ID }}'
  }],
  payment_behavior="default_incomplete",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You can create a field in your models.py to keep that if the user paid the money once, It will change to True, It will be False default.

when user is paying you can change this field to True and next times you can check if this field is not True, You have handle pay processing for first time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course, I can do like that. The problem is that the user should pay two times-one for an initial charge, one for a monthly charge-and this is bad experience for the user.

Comment: A better way would be to ::- To include a one-time charge or discount to the first subscription invoice, you can do so by adding an invoice item to the customer before creating the subscription. This can be done using the API or directly in the Stripe Dashboard. Read more here - https://support.stripe.com/questions/add-a-one-time-fee-or-discount-with-a-new-subscription-plan